# ENOBUFS when creating to many sockets with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, sockets, socket.io

**What I am trying to do:**

I write a node.js client/server application which uses persistent websocket connections (no longpolling). I want to stress test my server in order to tune it's performance and know the limits so that I can block new incoming connections due to overloads. Unfortunately I am stuck at one specific amount of socket connections every time, thus I think it may be related to OS or node settings.

**The problem:**

I have one client which creates 10k socket connections and the server can handle this perfectly fine. When I start the second client with another 10k connections I start getting the following errors on my client application once the server helds 14k concurrent connections:

> engine.io-client:socket socket close with reason: "transport error"
>   +0ms   engine.io-client:socket socket error {"type":"TransportError","description":{"code":"ENOBUFS","errno":"ENOBUFS","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":5433,"type":"error","target":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":4,"_socket":null,"_ultron":null,"_closeReceived":false,"bytesReceived":0,"readyState":0,"supports":{"binary":true},"extensions":{},"_isServer":false,"url":"ws://127.0.0.1:5433/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket","protocolVersion":13,"binaryType":"buffer"}}}
>   +0ms

**My client1.js and client2.js look like this:**

```
function createClient(){
    var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://127.0.0.1:5433', {transports:['websocket']});

    socket.connect();

    // Send a bit data every 2.5s to simulate a bit traffic
    setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit("sessionCheck", "ok");
    }, 2500);
}

var clients=0;
var id =setInterval(function() {
    createClient();
    clients++;
    if(clients >= 10000)
        clearInterval(id);
}, 1);
```

**My server.js looks like this:**

```
var http = require('http');
var httpServer = http.createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io')(httpServer, {pingTimeout: 60 * 1000, pingInterval: 5 * 1000});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('sessionCheck',  function(data){onSessionCheck(socket,data)});
});

setInterval(function(){
    console.log(io.engine.clientsCount + " websockets are connected");
}, 5000);

httpServer.listen(5433, "0.0.0.0", 5000); // port, hostname, backlog

console.log("server running now...");

function onSessionCheck(){
    //console.log("Incoming check");
}

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(500);
                return res.end('Error loading index.html');
            }

            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(data);
        })
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, as I already assumed, an option in windows (MaxUserPort), which you can change in the regedit. Check the MSDN description to learn more about it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196271 . You can set it to a maxmimum value of 65534.

Answer (score 1):

You said in Slack you already know about `–max-old-space-size` and you tried it and it did not help. Now I can confirm that using this option (i tried values 2048-65000) prevents me from getting more than ~18-20k concurrent connections from one server to one server. Removing the option gives me ~29500 concurrent connections. I use $20 DigitalOcean vps (2 GB, 2 core) and 29500 takes all the free memory of my server - that is why i cant have more connections for now.

**UPDATE**

Linux? 
Try check tuning the following values on server:

- `net.nf_conntrack_max` (i use `65536`)
- `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max` (i use `65536`)
- `cat /proc/sys/fs/nr_open` gives `1048576` for me
- `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr` gives `5056    0       2097152` for me
- `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max` gives `2097152` for me
- `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` (i use `2000 65535`)
- `net.core.somaxconn` (i use `65000`)
- `ulimit -n` gives me `1048576`

This may give you an inkling how to set the params https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/sysctl-conf/

Maybe you should check some of the values for your client-servers (like `ip_local_port_range`, `file-nr`, `ulimit -n`)

You might want to check logs (`/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/syslog`, `dmesg`) as well.

I finally got 34469 connections and then oom-killer killed node on my client machine

Comment: I am using Windows and I still hit a relatively low amount of max connections (13.5k) on a powerful windows server which has plenty ram and cpu free. I tried removing the max-old-space-size parameter without any effect. At some point the server is losing connections (most likely because the client/server doesn't respond to ping/pongs within the given timeout anymore).